# WPF SelectedItem not working in MVVM

Tags: wpf, datagrid, mvvm, selecteditem

I'm trying to display the data from two sql ce 3.5 sp1 database tables linked with foreign key - Customers and Orders. When the customer is selected in a datadrig, I want the other grid to be populated with the Orders.
I'm using a query:

```
var profiles = from c in db.Customers.Include("Orders")
                           select c;
```

And in my ViewModel:

```
private Models.Customers _selecteditem;
        public Models.Customers SelectedItem
        {
            get { return _selecteditem; }

        }
```

the view looks like this:

```
<Grid>
        <toolkit:DataGrid  x:Name="dg1" ItemsSource="{Binding Customers}" SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedItem, mode=TwoWay}">
            </toolkit:DataGrid>
        <toolkit:DataGrid  x:Name="dg2" ItemsSource="{Binding Path=SelectedItem.Orders}">
        </toolkit:DataGrid>
    </Grid>
```

The error I'm getting is:

```
Warning 1   Field 'Clients.ViewModels.CustomerViewModel._selecteditem' is never assigned to, and will always have its default value null
```

How to make it work correctly? When I just want to display Customers it is ok.
Thanks for any suggestions.

Answer (score 15):

You need a setter for SelectedItem

```
private Models.Customers _selecteditem;
public Models.Customers SelectedItem
{
    get { return _selecteditem; }
    set { _selectedItem = value; }
}
```

Also, since you are using it in a binding you'll want the ViewModel to implement [INotifyPropertyChanged](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.inotifypropertychanged.aspx) so it'll actually be:

```
private Models.Customers _selecteditem;
public Models.Customers SelectedItem
{
    get { return _selecteditem; }
    set
    { 
      if (_selectedItem != value)
      {
        _selectedItem = value;
        NotifyPropertyChanged("SelectedItem");
      }
    }
}

public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

private void NotifyPropertyChanged(String info)
{
    if (PropertyChanged != null)
    {
        PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(info));
    }
}
```

Comment: After I changed the code according to what you wrote above, no data are display at all by both datagrids.

Comment: @EVA If you repost your code as you have it now, I can see what you're missing. The code I gave you was just a sample to point you in the right direction, and may not work as is. Look up INotifyPropertyChanged and WPF Binding to understand *why* the code is written the way it is and you should be able to adapt it to your use case.

Comment: @MartinHarris : hello Martin, I am facing a similar issue, could you please have a look at my question and guide me where I have gone wrong? Thanks.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14816687/datagrid-selecteditem-and-databinding/14819813#comment20834969_14819813

Answer (score 1):

If Martin's answer doesn't help, have a look at the DataGrid.SelectionUnit and make sure it is set to "**FullRow**" not to "CellOrRowHeader" like I had it.

If you have it set to "CellOrRowHeader", the first click on a cell will set the SelectedItem to null.
I thought I'd add this in case someone else had the same annoying issue.