# Datagrid selectedItem and databinding

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, wpf-controls, wpfdatagrid

I have two datagrid displayed on my UI. When I select a particular row on datagrid 1, I would like to display the details of the datagrid 1 on datagrid 2. I am populating the datagrid data from a database.
here is the two database table structure.

Note: both the table are mapped by the personid in the database

[image: Person Table]

[image: PersonDetails Table]

here is the code so far I have tried

Baseclass.cs

```
public class Baseclass
{
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    protected void SetProperty<T>(ref T member, T value, [CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
    {
        member = value;
        this.RaiseNotification(propertyName);
    }

    protected void RaiseNotification(string propertyName)
    {
        if (this.PropertyChanged != null)
        {
            this.PropertyChanged.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
    }
}
```

person.cs

```
public class person : Baseclass
{

    private int personID;
    public int PersonID
    {
        get { return personID; }
        set { this.SetProperty<int>(ref this.personID, value); }
    }

    private string firstName;
    public string FirstName
    {
        get { return firstName; }
        set { this.SetProperty<string>(ref this.firstName, value); }
    }

    private string lastName;
    public string LastName
    {
        get { return lastName; }
        set { this.SetProperty<string>(ref this.lastName, value); }
    }

    Model _personModel = new Model();
    private ObservableCollection<person> _person = new ObservableCollection<person>();
    public ObservableCollection<person> Getpersons
    {
        get { return _person; }
        set { _person = value; OnPropertyChanged("GetPersons"); }
    }

    public person()
    {
        initializeload();
    }

    private void initializeload()
    {
        try
        {
            DataTable table = _personModel.getData();

            for (int i = 0; i < table.Rows.Count; ++i)
                Getpersons.Add(new person
                {
                 PersonID = Convert.ToInt32(table.Rows[i][0]),
                 FirstName = table.Rows[i][1].ToString(),
                 LastName = table.Rows[i][2].ToString(),
                });
        }

        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
        }
    }
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    private void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyname)
    {
        var handler = PropertyChanged;
        if (handler != null)
            handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyname));
    }

    public class Model
    {
        public DataTable getData()
        {
            DataTable ndt = new DataTable();
            SqlConnection sqlcon = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["MyConnectionString"].ConnectionString);
            sqlcon.Open();
            SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM [Person].[dbo].[persons]", sqlcon);
            da.Fill(ndt);
            da.Dispose();
            sqlcon.Close();
            return ndt;
        }
    }

}
```

PersonDetail class

```
public  class PersonDetails : Baseclass
{
    private int personID;
    public int PersonID
    {
        get { return personID; }
        set { this.SetProperty<int>(ref this.personID, value); }
    }

    private string address;
    public string Address
    {
        get { return address; }
        set { this.SetProperty<string>(ref this.address, value); }
    }

    private string pos;
    public string Position
    {
        get { return pos; }
        set { this.SetProperty<string>(ref this.pos, value); }
    }

    DetailsModel _detailModel = new DetailsModel();
    private ObservableCollection<PersonDetails> _details = new ObservableCollection<PersonDetails>();
    public ObservableCollection<PersonDetails> GetDetails
    {
        get { return _details; }
        set { _details = value; OnPropertyChanged("GetDetails"); }
    }
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    private void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyname)
    {
        var handler = PropertyChanged;
        if (handler != null)
            handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyname));
    }

    public PersonDetails()
    {
        initializeload();
    }

    private void initializeload()
    {
        try
        {
            DataTable table = _detailModel.getData();

            for (int i = 0; i < table.Rows.Count; ++i)
                GetDetails.Add(new PersonDetails
                {
                    PersonID = Convert.ToInt32(table.Rows[i][0]),
                    Address = table.Rows[i][1].ToString(),
                    Position = table.Rows[i][2].ToString(),                        
                });
        }

        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
        }
    }
    public class DetailsModel
    {
        public DataTable getData()
        {
            DataTable ndt = new DataTable();
            SqlConnection sqlcon = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["MyConnectionString"].ConnectionString);
            sqlcon.Open();
            SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM [Person].[dbo].[personDetails]", sqlcon);
            da.Fill(ndt);
            da.Dispose();
            sqlcon.Close();
            return ndt;
        }
    }
}
```

MainViewModel.cs

```
    public class MainViewModel : Base, INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public MainViewModel()
    {
    }

    private ObservableCollection<person> personValues;
    public ObservableCollection<person> Persons
    {
        get { return personValues; }
        set
        {
            this.SetProperty<ObservableCollection<person>>(ref this.personValues, value);
        }
    }

    private ObservableCollection<PersonDetails> detailsValues;
    public ObservableCollection<PersonDetails> Details
    {
        /* This is correct below ?? I have an error as 
        'PersonDemo.MainViewModel' does not contain a definition for 'GetDetails' and no extension method 'GetDetails' accepting a first argument of type 'PersonDemo.MainViewModel' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)*/
        get { return this.GetDetails(this.Selectedperson.PersonID); }
    }

    private person selectedValue;
    public person Selectedperson
    {
        get { return selectedValue; }
        set
        {
            this.SetProperty<person>(ref this.selectedValue, value);
            this.RaiseNotification("Details");
        }
    }


}
```

XAML

```
  <Grid>
  <DataGrid Margin="100,20,116,211" ItemsSource="{Binding Persons}" SelectedItem="{Binding Selectedperson}"  />
  <DataGrid Margin="100,130,116,101" ItemsSource="{Binding Details}" />
  </Grid>
```

can anybody help to proceed in writing the MainViewModel? I am stuck here since weeks.

Comment: what's the problem with your code? it does not work at all, it works with certain bug? Its good that you have much code but let us know also what the trouble is

Comment: At which line do u find the bug?  My question is to find the right way to code the ViewModel. What u see here is the View and the Model only.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

First, I recomend to use the `INotifyPropertyChanged` interface in the base class. Maybe you use it and forget write it in the sample code. For make this with MVVM patter, you need to implement a ViewModel for both data grids. Let's call it in our example `BothGridViewModel`, you may call it as you want. Then in this view model you need the collection of all person, let's call it `AllPerson`, then you need to have a property of `Person` type, when you will have the selected person in the grid, let's call it `SelectedPerson`. It will be something like this:

```
public class BothGridViewModel:INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    ...
    public ObservableCollection<Person> AllPersons {...}
    public Person SelectedPerson {...}
    ...
}
```

All you need, is to set it in the DataContext of the View. And bindings:

```
<YourView DataContext={Binding SomeBothGridViewModelClass}>
    <Grid>
     <DataGrid Margin="100,20,116,211" ItemsSource="{Binding AllPersons}" SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedPerson}"  />
     <DataGrid Margin="100,130,116,101" ItemsSource="{Binding SelectedPerson.Getpersons}" /> <!--Or some SelectedPerson.PersonDetails.GetDetails-->
  </Grid>
</YourView DataContext={Binding SomeBothGridViewModelClass}>
```

I think this is the good view model structure for make what you want. Hope this helps you...

---

EDIT

---

I see your point now, you have two database tables, one for the main properties and other for the details. I see two good ways for doing this:
1) The first one, is that I don't belive that the second datagrid is necesary due for each person you don't have a collection of details. Instead you may use a grid, and other controls for showing the properties. Also I think you must to implement a view model for the person, for instance:

```
public class PersonViewModel:INotifyPropertyChanged
{
     public string FirstName {...}
     public string LastName {...}
     //Other properties

     public PersonDetails Details {...}
}
```

Then in the grid, you may bind the items source to a collection of `PersonViewModel` then you can make bindings to the selected item of the grid, for instance:

```
<Grid>
    <DataGrid x:Name="dataGrid" ItemsSource={Binding AllPersonViewModels}/>
    ...
    <!--Then some combo box, text block or text box binding to a property of the selected item's details-->
          ...
          <TextBox Text={Binding SelectedItem.Details.Address, ElementName=dataGrid}/>
          ...
<Grid>
```

2) The second way I think could be done, is showing all data in the same datagrid. For this you need to do the `PersonViewModel` class in this way:

```
public class PersonViewModel:INotifyPropertyChanged
{
     public string FirstName {...}
     public string LastName {...}
     //Other properties

     //Then the Details properties
     public string Address {...}
     //...
     //Note this class is like a wrapper for person, and person details
}
```

This way is a bit simpler, but maybe cause an unwanted database over access.

---

EDIT 2

---

After have a look of your code, I have to say a few things about it: In the `PersonViewModel` and `PersonDetailViewModel` you should use a `DispatcherTimer` instead a `Timer`, because we are in Wpf. Other thing, maybe you should use a Repository pattern, to create a `PersonRepository` and a `PersonDetailRepository` where to put all the DB comunication, in fact, `PersonViewModel` and `PersonDetailViewModel` are a in some way, repositories, but by now you don't need to change it, it should work. I'm going to show you here the code of the `MainViewModel`, I nodified it to have the SelectedPersonDetail property, in this way, all you need to do is make a binding in the View:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using tryout13022013.PersonViewModels;
using System.ComponentModel;
using tryout13022013.DetailsViewModel;
using tryout13022013.PersonModel;

namespace tryout13022013
{
    public class MainViewModel
    {
        private PersonViewModel _subPerson = new PersonViewModel();
        public PersonViewModel SubPerson
        {
            get 
            {
                return _subPerson;
            }
            set
            {
                if (_subPerson != value)
                {
                    _subPerson = value; OnPropertyChanged("SubPerson");

                }
            }
        }


        private PersonDetailsViewModel _subDetail = new PersonDetailsViewModel();
        public PersonDetailsViewModel SubDetail
        {
            get { return _subDetail; }
            set 
            {
                _subDetail = value; OnPropertyChanged("SubDetail");
            }

        }

        private Person _selectedPerson;
        public Person SelectedPerson
        {
            get { return _selectedPerson; }
            set {
                if (_selectedPerson != value)
                {
                    _selectedPerson = value;
                    OnPropertyChanged("SelectedPerson");
                    OnPropertyChanged("SelectedPersonDetail");  //In this way when Change the Selected Person, the Selected Detail will be changed again...
                    //if (this.SelectedPerson != null && this.SubDetail != null)
                    //{
                       // I dont know how to call the PersonDetailsViewModel class like a method here in order to load its data. kindly help
                       //this.SubDetail.MethodforLoadingPersonDetails(this.SelectedPerson);
                    //}
                }
            }

        }

        public PersonDetails SelectedPersonDetail
        {
            get
            {
                if (SubDetail == null || SelectedPerson ==null)
                    return  null;
                return SubDetails.DetailsData.FirstOrDefault(detail => detail.PersonID == SelectedPerson.PersonID);
            }           

        }


        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

        private void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyname)
        {
            var handler = PropertyChanged;
            if (handler != null)
                handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyname));
        }
    }
}
```

And this is an instace of a binding you can make in your View, in this case for selecting the item in the second grid:

```
<Window x:Class="tryout13022013.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:person="clr-namespace:tryout13022013.PersonViewModels"
    xmlns:details="clr-namespace:tryout13022013.DetailsViewModel"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
<Grid>
    <DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding SubPerson.PersonData}"  SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedPerson, Mode=TwoWay}"
        AutoGenerateColumns="False" Height="77" HorizontalAlignment="Left"
        Margin="101,26,0,0" Name="dataGrid1" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="auto" >
        <DataGrid.DataContext>
            <person:PersonViewModel/>
        </DataGrid.DataContext>
        <DataGrid.Columns>
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="ID" Width="auto" Binding="{Binding PersonID}"/>
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="First Name" Width="auto" Binding="{Binding FirstName}"/>
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Last Name" Width="auto" Binding="{Binding LastName}"/>     
        </DataGrid.Columns>
    </DataGrid>


    <DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding SubDetail.DetailsData}" 
        AutoGenerateColumns="False" Height="77" HorizontalAlignment="Left" 
        Margin="101,135,0,0" Name="dataGrid2" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="255" SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedPersonDetail, Mode=OneWayToSource}">
        <DataGrid.DataContext>
            <details:PersonDetailsViewModel/>
        </DataGrid.DataContext>
        <DataGrid.Columns>
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="ID" Width="auto" Binding="{Binding PersonID}"/>
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Address" Width="auto" Binding="{Binding Address}"/>
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Position" Width="auto" Binding="{Binding Description}"/>
        </DataGrid.Columns>
    </DataGrid>
</Grid>
```

I forgot it, you need to make the binding to `SubPerson.PersonData` and `SubDetail.DetailsData`, these are the collection.
Check it out...

Comment: Thanks for your followup.. the first one sounds something similar but not exactly , and the second option is something which I dont need. I have two different tables in a database. I need to display as two different datagrids, when I click the personID=1 in datagrid1, the datagrid 2 should display only the details which belongs to the personID=1. I will add my complete code and post it here, kindly have a look you will get a complete overview about my problem. Many thanks

Comment: https://gist.github.com/userXemY/eb3dff1b7d5f5930d3b6
this is the link to my entire project. and the database tables is found in this question.

Comment: There is a thing I don't understand, if the relationship is One-to-One, then for each item that you select in the first datagrid, will be only one item that will be showed in the second one, so you will have a complete data grid for showing only one item. Is this what you want?

Comment: yes, the relationship is 1:1, for each id in the first datagrid the second grid has the to show the respective address and description. if u don understand pls ask me again. thanks indeed.

Comment: I am going to try out and get back to u Raul

Comment: where is FirstOrDefault() method defined here ? Just to ask you, did the above solution work for u..

Comment: Sorry, I can't enter the chat, it is to slow for me, just said Loading WPF Just a second... (for ever)

Comment: FirstOrDefault is a IEnumerable<T> Linq's method, using it you may take the first item in a collection. I didn't test the app, but if all DB access are ok, should works.

Comment: ok Raul, actually i am in CET time zone, my PC at home is very slow to test.. I am gonna check tomo at university and if everything is fine , I will let u know. Thanks a lot for ur support so far.

Comment: I have the following error 
'tryout13022013.DetailsViewModel.PersonDetailsViewModel' does not contain a definition for 'FirstOrDefault' and no extension method 'FirstOrDefault' accepting a first argument of type 'tryout13022013.DetailsViewModel.PersonDetailsViewModel' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Comment: Sorry, I had made an code update to the answer, I chanded the PersonDetails, to PersonDetails.Data , due that is the collection. Linq´s methods only are apply to generic IEnumerable collections.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your effort so far to help me to find a soltuion. this didn not work for me. I hav no errors when I added this edited solution and I have an empty output. I have finaly done it in a little bit another way.. I will post my solution here, it may help others. thanks Raul, I really appreciate your help so far :-)

Comment: You are welcome, if you need another question you can send me a personal email rulyotano@gmail.com.

Answer (score 4):

Having had a chat with Buba1947 in [WPF](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/18165/wpf) room, I've concluded that she's actually got a 1-1 relation split table in database that she's actually trying to show as such in the split data grids.

I've proposed her to create a `PersonViewModel` on top of `Person` & `PersonDetails` tables so her `MainViewModel` contains only one `ObservableCollection<PersonViewModel>` under the `Persons` property to which we shall bind the two `DataGrids`.

so MainViewModel.cs (the DataContext) has:

```
private ObservableCollection<PersonViewModel> personValues; 
public ObservableCollection<PersonViewModel> Persons 
{ 
    get { return personValues; } 
    set { this.SetProperty<ObservableCollection<PersonViewModel>>(ref this.personValues, value); } 
}
```

The data adaptor is changed to bring the data in using an inner join with relevant query being something along the lines of this (which fills the Persons property above):

```
"SELECT * FROM [Person].[dbo].[persons] INNER JOIN [Person].[dbo].[personDetails] ON [Person].[dbo].[persons].[Id] = [Person].[dbo].[personDetails].[Id]"
```

Next we shall bind a `CollectionViewSource` to Persons in Xaml:

```
<Window.Resources>
    <CollectionViewSource x:Key="PersonsData" Source={Binding Persons} />
</Window.Resources>
```

and bind `DataGrids` to this with individual columns:

```
<DataGrid ItemsSource={Binding Source={StaticResource PersonsData}} AutoGenerateColumns="false">
    <DataGrid.Columns>
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Person Id" Content={Binding PersonId} />
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="First Name" Content={Binding FirstName} />
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Last Name" Content={Binding LastName} />
    </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>

<DataGrid ItemsSource={Binding Source={StaticResource PersonsData}} AutoGenerateColumns="false">
    <DataGrid.Columns>
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Person Id" Content={Binding PersonId} />
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Address" Content={Binding Address} />
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Position" Content={Binding Position} />
    </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>
```

Note: there may be typo in here as I haven't got VS to hand, please let me know if I need to fix something. I've written all of this from memory.